# What is the best way to fix a large rectangular shaped glass table top?

Tags: repair, furniture, glass

It's a 48in wide x 84 or 96in long x 1/2in thick. It broke pretty clean down the middle widthwise. Also it has an arched wooden base with 2 arms arching outwards (one on either side) in the outer middle of table centered and 2 arms on either end centered at the heads of said table. It has to be able to withstand food for 8 people and be able to withstand hot and or cold foods like a 28lbs Turducken for holiday dinners as well as all the fixings.

Comment: I'd talk to a glass shop and order a replacement....

Answer (score 1):

Call up a glass shop and order a hunk of **tempered** glass the right size. You can't change the size or shape after it's ordered (tempered glass can't be cut after tempering), so get the size exactly right.

The one you had was not tempered, or you'd have a few thousand more pieces - which is a lot safer than one that breaks into fewer large sharp pieces.

Tempered glass is much stronger than normal glass of the same thickness, so one the same thickness should hold up to your use, but you could always go to 3/4" or 1" thick tempered for even more durability while staying with glass.

*Or go with a few thousand years of experience and choose wood ;-)*

Comment: Top tip: let the glass shop deliver and install it. Your back will thank you, and if there are any tempering stresses, the ride over will probably reveal those and it'll remain the problem of the glass shop.